# how to implement incremental backup for mysql server?

Tags: mysql, backup, database-backups

how to make incremental backup using mysql ? somebody help me i'm struggle

```
mysqlbackup --apply-log --incremental [--use-memory=MB] [--uncompress]
                [--ibbackup=IBBACKUP-BINARY]
                INCREMENTAL-BACKUP-MY.CNF FULL-BACKUP-MY.CNF
```

Comment: using binarylog concept